# Any way to call Managed Code from DLL Main in .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net

Any way to call Managed Code from DLL Main in .Net 4.5?

I am trying to develop a application to execute managed code in remote process.

currently, I develop a Cpp dll which load managed assembly in DLLMain and execute a static method.

and i use CreateRemotedThread to make remote process to call LoadLibrary to load that cpp dll and  dllmain will be performed automatically.

now i got the exception:**Attempting managed execution inside OS Loader lock. Do not attempt to run managed code inside a DllMain or image initialization function since doing so can cause the application to hang.**

after search in MSDN and google, i notice the root cause is that executing managed code in Dllmain

so my question is:

1. any way to call managed code in my case
2. and other solution can execute managed code in remote process

Comment: That's a clear "no".  Injecting the CLR into another process is also a setup for disappointment.  That of course can't work if it already has the CLR loaded.  Only ever contemplate injecting unmanaged code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to call managed code from unmanaged code is to enable COM-visibility for the managed code assembly, and then use COM to call it from the unmanaged code.

There's a good example here; it's quite old but it is still relevant:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736